# Applescript : refer to an app from a variable

Tags: applescript, safari

I sometime use Safari, sometime Safari Technology Preview,
I was thinking that would be nice to just refer it once in a variable a bit like this

```
set SafariBuild to "Safari Technology Preview"

tell application SafariBuild to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"icon-chevron-left\\\"]\")[0].click();" in tab 2 of window 1
```

Obviously that's not working, but is there something in the same spirt that would refer to an app without changing all the ***tell application*** ?

Comment: The target for the tell statement is needed at compile time.

Comment: On a side note, I have found that using a single-quote `'` inside if the double-quotes `"` of `do JavaScript " ... ;"` in many cases will keep from having to use `\\\"`. You might want it give it a try, as all of that escaping with multiple backslash is such a pain.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment by red_menace, "The target for the tell statement is needed at compile time."; however, here is an alternative method:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set SafariBuild to "Safari Technology Preview"

if (SafariBuild's contents = "Safari") then
    tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"icon-chevron-left\\\"]\")[0].click();" in tab 2 of window 1
else if (SafariBuild's contents = "Safari Technology Preview") then
    tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"icon-chevron-left\\\"]\")[0].click();" in tab 2 of window 1
end if
```

Or you could use `choose from list`, as in this *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
choose from list {"Safari", "Safari Technology Preview"}
if result is not false then
    set SafariBuild to result as text
else
    return
end if

if (SafariBuild's contents = "Safari") then
    tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"icon-chevron-left\\\"]\")[0].click();" in tab 2 of window 1
else if (SafariBuild's contents = "Safari Technology Preview") then
    tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"icon-chevron-left\\\"]\")[0].click();" in tab 2 of window 1
end if
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible without if statement but there is thousand of lines in my script, I'll just go with a search / replace for now then. Thank you